# Is there a third party tool that helps me create a server for windows MDM agent

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm

I want to create a MDM server where a set of windows phone with MDM agent can register to.

During my investigation I found, a MDM agent on windows phone can be registered to only 1 server and once registered will only talk to that server.

I want to monitor these phones and want to extract some information from the registered windows phone. If I can control the server I can make all the required API calls to monitor them properly.

Any pointers will be of great help.